# Calling function from within class throws NameError

Tags: python, class

My code:

```py
class thing:
    def do_thigy(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        do_thigy()

a = thing()
```

results:

```py
NameError: name 'do_thigy' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's a method of the class, you must call it as a method
use `self.do_thigy()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can follow from this

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        print('Hi')
    @staticmethod
    def test2():
        Foo.test()

Foo.test2()
```

prints:

```
Hi
```

or
for the same question you can find the solution from the stack overflow by going to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024306/calling-a-method-from-the-same-class)